# Decreasing font size in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to achieve the following effect in rails:

If the text is bigger than x characters then make it smaller, the next x characters smaller, the next character smaller, ad infinitum

for example x = 7 would output the following html

```
Lorem i<small>psum do<small>lor sit<small> amet, <small>consecte
<small>tur adip<small>isicing</small></small></small></small></small></small>
```

and the css would be `small {font-size: 95%}`

What is an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moritz's answer seems fine, dry-code attempt at iterative version:

```
def shrink(what,chunk=5)
  result = ''
  0.step(what.length, chunk) do |i|
    if i<what.length
      result << '<small>' if i>0
      result << what[i,chunk]
    end
  end
  result << '</small>'*(what.length/chunk)
  result
end
```

Comment: seems 'shrink' fits pretty well :-)

Comment: hm. your implementation doesn't leave the first characters unshrinked. minor issue.

Comment: Are you sure?  That's the intention of the post-fix "if i>0"

Comment: Thank you very much to you both, moritz and fd!

Answer (score 2):

hm. maybe some helper with some recursion?

```
def shrink(what)
  if ( what.length > 5)
    "#{what[0,4]}<small>#{shrink(what[5,what.length()-1])}</small>"
  else
    what
  end
end
```

there is a better way to write the recursive call for certain, but i don't know it right know.